# Filter by two values. Django ORM

Tags: django

I need to filter objects by price. How to do something like this?

```
from_price = request.GET['from']
to = request.GET['to']

o = Data.objects.filter(price > from_price and price < to  )
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need inclusive price amounts you can use the [`__range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) (between) operator:

```
o = Data.objects.filter(price__range=(from, to))
```

Otherwise, just use [`__gt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt) (greater than) and [`__lt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt) (less than):

```
o = Data.objects.filter(price__gt=from, price__lt=to))
```

For more operators, take a look at Django's [QuerySet API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) specially the [Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) section.

Answer (score 0):

From the [query documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/):

```
o = Data.objects.filter(price__gt=from_price).filter(price__lt=to)
```

Comment: As many as you want, Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated.

Comment: There is no need to chain the filters since AND is the default

Answer (score 0):

```
o = Data.objects.filter(price__gt=from_price).filter(price__lt=to)
```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#gt) on this.